# UILocalNotification and UISwitch remember state

Tags: ios, xcode

I made an UISwitch, and when it is switched on, my app sends 10 notifications with a "repeat interval". It works all fine. But the problem is, when I want to save (remember) the state of my UISwitch and load it, the UILocalNotification aren't being sent anymore.

This is my code:

For the save of the UISwitch state and notification launch:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    BOOL test= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switch"];
    NSLog(@"%@",test?@"YES":@"NO");
    [self.alarmSwitch setOn:test animated:YES];
}

- (void) switchIsChanged:(UISwitch *)paramSender{

    if ([paramSender isOn]){



            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:self.alarmSwitch.on forKey:@"switch"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];






            notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
            notification1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0];
            [notification1 setAlertBody:@"U moet uw voeten controleren!"];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];


            notification1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10.0];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];


        }
}
```

How can I save the state of the UISwitch in another way in order to get this work? Or is there another solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `switchIsChanged:` method isn't going to be firing when you set the on state programatically.  I would recommend moving the code that handles the notifications out of the `switchIsChanged:` method.  Example:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    BOOL test= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switch"];
    NSLog(@"%@",test?@"YES":@"NO");
    [self.alarmSwitch setOn:test animated:YES];

    // initially detect if we should fire the bnotifications
    if ([self.alarmSwitch isOn]) {

        [self fireNotifications];

    }

}

-(void)switchIsChanged:(UISwitch *)paramSender{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:paramSender.on forKey:@"switch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    if ([paramSender isOn]){

        [self fireNotifications];

    }
}

-(void)fireNotifications {

    notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    notification1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0];
    [notification1 setAlertBody:@"U moet uw voeten controleren!"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];

    notification1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10.0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];

}
```

Note: you may have to make sure that the notifications aren't firing more than once which may cause bugs since `viewWillAppear:` can be called multiple times.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the possible problem you mentoined... How can I fix this?

Comment: Add a boolean variable to denote whether notifications have been fired or not.  In `fireNotifications`, check to make sure that the notifications haven't been fired before.  If they haven't, then fire them and set the boolean to `YES`.  When the switch changes to off, set this boolean to `NO` since the notifications are off.

Comment: I understand it a little bit, but not too much.. Could you send me an email with good explanation? stylo.apple@gmail.com, thanks!